# How to daemonize a process that inherits all parents threads?

Tags: operating-system, pthreads, fork, daemon

I have a process that creates multiple threads and creates a socket.
Now i want to create a daemon process by calling a fork() and exit the parent process.
But the threads that are created by parent process get exited when parent is killed.
Is there a way I can inherit those threads and socket to child process ?
(Code is run in CPP)

Answer (score 0):

> But the threads that are created by parent process get exited when parent is killed.

Not exactly.  The parent's threads are unaffected, and the child only ever gets the thread that called `fork()`.  This is not the same thing as the child getting the other threads, and them thereafter terminating.  In particular, no cancellation handlers or exit handlers that may have been registered by them are called in the child, and this may leave mutexes and other synchronization objects in an unusable and unrecoverable state.  Cleaning up such a mess is the intended purpose of *fork* handlers, but those are tricky to use correctly, and they must be used consistently throughout the process to be effective.

> I there a way I can inherit those threads and socker to child process ?

A child process inherits its parent's open file descriptors automatically, so nothing special needs to be done about the socket.  But the other threads? No.

[The POSIX documentation for `fork`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) is explicit about all this:

> The new process (child process) shall be an exact copy of the calling
> process (parent process) except as detailed below:
>
> [...]
>
> - The child process shall have its own copy of the parent's file descriptors. Each of the child's file descriptors shall refer to the
>   same open file description with the corresponding file descriptor of
>   the parent.
>
> [...]
>
> - A process shall be created with a single thread. If a multi-threaded process calls `fork()`, the new process shall contain a
>   replica of the calling thread and its entire address space, possibly
>   including the states of mutexes and other resources. Consequently, to
>   avoid errors, the child process may only execute async-signal-safe
>   operations until such time as one of the exec functions is called.
>
>   When the application calls `fork()` from a signal handler and any of the fork handlers registered by `pthread_atfork()` calls a function that
>   is not async-signal-safe, the behavior is undefined.

If the objective of forking is to disassociate from the original session and parent in order to run in the background as a daemon, then your best bet is for the initial thread to do that immediately upon startup, before creating any additional threads or opening any sockets.